# Traversing directories and performing command prompt commands in each with Python

Tags: python

In Windows 7 Pro, I need to traverse directories at a given location (in this case Z:\) and perform command prompt commands in each using Python. This seems like it should be straightforward with `os.walk()`, but nothing I've tried so far has worked--the closest I've gotten is to have the commands infinitely loop from my desktop (that script is below). What do I need to do to accomplish this task?

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Z:/"):
    for dir in dirs:
        os.system('cd Z:\\' + dir)
        os.system('git init')
        os.system('git add .')
        os.system('git commit -m \"Initial\"')
```

Comment: First off, doing os.system('cd Z:\\' + dir) won't actually change your working directory (it will change it for that command, and then when that command finishes, you'll be back at your starting point.  You can try os.chdir(dir) but I'm not entirely sure how chdir and stupid archaic drive letters interact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `os.system('cd WHEREVER')` you are creating a new command shell which has its own idea of the current directory.

When that shell exits, the parent process does not retain the current directory of the child process, so that the subsequent `os.system()` calls don't see any change in their current directory.

The right way to do this is to change the current directory in the **parent** process (your script) which will be **inherited** by the child process:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Z:/"):
    for dir in dirs:
        os.chdir('Z:\\' + dir)
        os.system('git init')
        os.system('git add .')
        os.system('git commit -m \"Initial\"')
```

Comment: Does this require some `os.path.join` magic? Like `path = os.path.join('Z:\\', dir)` and `os.chdir(path)` to make sure it is readable by Windows? And I would add that he could include some tests with `os.path.exists(path)` this way. I am commenting to clarify for myself; file manipulations in Windows always get me.

Comment: @Engineero, agreed that it would be good cross-platform practice to use `os.path.*` rather than just glom strings together, but I'm trying to make the minimal changes to the OP's code without getting bogged down in other issues. The path in question must exist because `os.walk` told us that it did, except in case it got `rmdir`'d while this script is running ;-)

Comment: I see, thanks for the  clarification and sorry to muddy the waters.

Comment: @Engineero, there are definitely other issues with this code. I recommended [never using `os.system` in another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294179/python-reading-whitespace-separated-file-lines-as-separate-lines/24294225#comment37542761_24294225) started by @Vaindil.