# Python reading whitespace-separated file lines as separate lines

Tags: python

This is on Windows Server 2008 R2. I have a file of inputs, one input per line. Some of the inputs have spaces in them. I'm trying to use the below simple code, but it separates out each word instead of each line. I should end up with 208 new folders (with any spaces stripped out) but I end up with 230 because of this. What do I need to change to correct the problem?

```
import os
f = open("out.txt", "r")
os.chdir("base location")
for line in f:
    os.system("mkdir " + line.strip())
```

(For example, "Download Samples" is one line in out.txt, but this script creates two folders, "Download" and "Samples".)

EDIT for clarity: I have a list of 208 names, 1 per line. Some of these names have spaces. I need to create one folder for each LINE in the directory `base location`. The above script is creating one folder per WORD, not per LINE. That's the problem I need to correct.

Comment: Please show some sample from `out.txt` which reproduces the problem.

Comment: try opening the file with 'rb'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a Python problem. This is an OS issue. I presume you're running Linux (you didn't say).

Running this:

```
mkdir Line with multiple words
```

... will create four directories, not one.

**UPDATE:** @bgporter explains this too.

The much better solution is not to use `os.system` (basically, ever) but to use `os.mkdir` instead:

```
import os
f = open("out.txt", "r")
os.chdir("base location")
for line in f:
    s = line.strip()
    if len(s)>0:
        # ignore blank or whitespace-only lines
        os.mkdir(s)
```

Comment: Shoot, didn't realize I didn't put the OS in there. It's there now: Server 2008 R2. Doesn't the `.strip()` remove that whitespace before the `mkdir` though?

Comment: `.strip()` only removes leading and trailing whitespace, not whitespace in the middle of the string: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip

Comment: @Vaindil, You also would not *want* to remove whitespace in the middle of the string...it changes the name of the directory.

Comment: I really need to learn my built-in functions. Thank you so much, this exactly fixed my problem (and makes complete sense).

Answer (score 2):

Without sample input it is hard to be sure, but it looks like you need to quote the directory creation.

```
for line in f:
    os.system("mkdir '%s'" % line.strip())
```

On Windows, the single quotes will cause undesirable effects, so using double quotes is probably necessary.

```
for line in f:
    os.system('mkdir "%s"' % line.strip())
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work. (It actually makes the problem worse by creating several additional directories and wrapping everything in single quotes.) I added sample data to the OP as well.

Comment: @Vaindil, I do not see the sample data.

Comment: It's in the parentheses directly underneath the code: "(For example, "Download Samples" is one line in out.txt, but this script creates two folders, "Download" and "Samples".)"

Comment: @Vaindil, I just tried my answer on a single text file with `Download Samples`, and a base location of `/tmp`. I cannot reproduce your problem with that one line, so it must be something else.

Comment: @merlin2011's solution would work for many cases under most Unix-like OSes. Hence the need to explain what OS you're running on when you ask for help with any OS-dependent problem.

Comment: @Dan, Yes the single quotes break things on Windows.

Comment: @Dan, I think escaped double quotes would probably fix it, but I do not have a Windows system to test on.

Comment: Escaped double quotes would only work if the filenames themselves **never** contain double-quotes. Basically, this is why I say **don't use `os.system` ever**. It tacitly interposes the shell between the calling and called process as an intermediate layer with its own very complicated syntactic rules... ripe for bugs and exploits.

Comment: @Dan, I strongly agree on the point of `os.system`. Your answer is definitely much better, so I gave you +1 on that.

Answer (score 2):

If you run:

`mkdir hello world`

in Linux, you will create two directories, one named "hello", and one named "world".

You need to run

`mkdir "hello world"`

in order to create a directory name that has a space in it.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here are all right -- the problem has to do with how Unix commands work -- if you want to use mkdir to create a directory with a name containing spaces, you have to either escape the spaces or put quotes around the name so that your Unix environment knows there is only one argument, and it has spaces in it; otherwise, it will make one directory per argument/word.

I just want to add 2 things:

1. Whenever you `open()` a file, you need to make sure you `close()` it. The easiest way to do this is to use a context manager, like `with open(file) as f:`.
2. `os` actually has a `mkdir` function that takes a string as an argument. You could just pass each line to `os.mkdir` as-is.

So, you could revise your code like this:

```
import os

with open("out.txt", "r") as f:
    os.chdir("base location")

    for line in f:
        os.mkdir(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This is the fix

```
import os
f = open("out.txt", "r")
os.chdir("base location")
for line in file:
    os.system("mkdir {}".format(line.strip().replace(" ", r"\ ")))
```

The problem is that `mkdir` interprets its input as a list of directories to make, unless you escape the spaces.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work. I added additional information to the OP that hopefully clears things up.

Comment: @Vaindil This should work now, I edited to match your edit to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
os.system("mkdir " + line.strip())
```

with

```
os.system("mkdir '{0}'".format(line.strip()))
```

By quoting the argument to `mkdir` you tell it to create a single directory that has a name containing whitespace. If the quotes are omitted, `mkdir` creates multiple directories instead.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work. (It actually makes the problem worse by creating several additional directories and wrapping everything in single quotes.)

Comment: I see now that you're not on *nix. @Dan's recommendation to use the Pytohn builtin mkdir command is the right one.