# Python os.chdir() not changing directory

Tags: python, bash, operating-system

So, I am following a simple tutorial "Python Tutorial: Automate Parsing and Renaming of Multiple Files" and am already encountering a problem where os.chdir() is not working.  I am on a Windows 10 system, running python 3.6, and I have tried using both my regular terminal (which has cygwin installed) and bash on ubuntu on Windows.

Here is the code:

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())

os.chdir('c:/Users/Michelle Kaiser/Desktop/Lab_Progs/PI3Kalpha')

print(os.getcwd())
```

Here is the reg terminal:

```
C:\Users\Michelle Kaiser\Desktop\Lab_Progs>python rename.py
C:\Users\Michelle Kaiser\Desktop\Lab_Progs

C:\Users\Michelle Kaiser\Desktop\Lab_Progs>`
```

The path that it is returning corresponds to the folder my program is located in.  I have moved the program 3 times to verify this.  Also, it's obviously returning a path only once, so it's probably not responding to the 2 print statements.

Here is the bash terminal:

```
mkaiser@ZIPPY:/mnt/c/Users/Michelle Kaiser/Desktop/Lab_Progs$ python rename.py
/mnt/c/Users/Michelle Kaiser/Desktop/Lab_Progs
mkaiser@ZIPPY:/mnt/c/Users/Michelle Kaiser/Desktop/Lab_Progs$
```

I also tried running the code with `os.path.exists()`, which did not change the output on either terminal.  I have definitely double checked that I am saving my program file from one test to the next.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you show your code with `os.path.exists()`? It only prints one line so it looks like your `os.chdir()` failed

Comment: You have two print statements but only a printed line. That looks suspicious.

Comment: I certainly agree, but it hasn't led me to any better ideas.  Other than checking that I hit save.

Comment: Code:    `import os

os.path.exists('c:/Users/Michelle Kaiser/Desktop/Lab_Progs/PI3Kalpha')

print(os.getcwd())`        Terminal:      `C:\Users\Michelle Kaiser\Desktop\Lab_Progs>python rename.py
C:\Users\Michelle Kaiser\Desktop\Lab_Progs

C:\Users\Michelle Kaiser\Desktop\Lab_Progs>`

Comment: So, essentially no change.  I'm still brainstorming this.  Since I'm operating with the os, could my dual boot be causing issues?  It's my first dual boot and I've had it for only a few months.  (And it had some weird issues with some files in /etc/, but I believe I fixed all of those.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been trying to change a file that has no whitespace.

It seems like this person has a similar problem:

[Python reading whitespace-separated file lines as separate lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294179/python-reading-whitespace-separated-file-lines-as-separate-lines)

Comment: If is similar to your problem why you don't try this solution. You need to put some peace of code, you need to put tag to your question.

Comment: Okay.  So, while this thread addresses a later point, which I hope to get to, I'm still just trying to get the terminal to respond with the full path.  It should have the final folder "/PI3Kalpha" at the end of the path.  Then, the next step will be to make my program list out all the files in that folder.  So, I don't need to make a directory at all.  Help me out, if I overlooked your point in the thread you linked.

Comment: I think I got it.  I've change my directory to not have a space in it.  Jeez.  It took awhile to hear you.  Thanks!